# Double spring problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, oscillators, coupled-oscillators

I have a problem trying to write the equations of motion for this system.
[image: Double spring system]

The first picture is a picture of a stationary state. After applying some force to object A, the system is represented in second (lower) picture. We assume that the origin is the wall, and that x-axis goes to the right.

If position of object A (shown with light-grey color) is x1, and position of object B (shown with dark-grey color) is x2, what are the equations of motion for object A and object B?

My understanding is that change of the length of the spring k2 equals $(x_2-x_1)$, therefore the force that spring creates equals $k_2*(x_2-x_1)$. The same logic applies for b2, but we have to use velocities instead of positions- the dampening force equals $b_2*(v_2-v_1)$.

Since spring k1 (and dampener b1) only affect object B, the force that they create equals $k_1*x_2$ and $b_1*v_1$.

With this, the equations of motion are:

Object A:

$\frac{m_Ad^2x_1}{dt} = -k_2(x_2-x_1)-b_2(v_2-v_1)$

Object B:

$\frac{m_Bd^2x_1}{dt} = -k_1x_2-b_1v_2- k_2(x_2-x_1)-b_2(v_2-v_1)$

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Note that questions like 'Is this right?' are poor fits for this site, as the answer (Yes/No) is too short to be a valid answer. You should consider changing the question to be more open-ended.

Comment: Your question was better before you edited it. Now you'll mostly get comments asking what you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x1 and x2 are the displacements of the objects to the right, then, in the equation for Object A, the signs of the two terms on the right hand side are incorrect.  Your equation for Object B is correct, except that the subscript on the left hand side should be a 2.  And, of course, the dt's should be $dt^2$ (as Crimson pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct, but there are some mistakes.

- Reconsider the direction of the forces. Now the force of the second spring acts in the same direction on both masses.
- In the notation of a second derivative the factor d$t$ is also squared.
- You assume the length of the spring at rest to be 0. (this is not necessarily a mistake)

Comment: That would mean that the second spring would have a positive result in the EOM (instead of $-k2(x2-x1)-b2(v2-v1)$ it would be $+k2(x2-x1)+b2(v2-v1)$ ) if I understood you correctly?

Comment: at least in one of the EOM. Try to think in which direction the force acts in a specific situation. For instance when x2>x1.